# Xcode 4.2 project hierarchy not matching with SVN

Tags: iphone, ios, svn, xcode4.2

Every project in Xcode 4.2 contains:
- info plists
- xcodeproj file
- folder 'project'

When I am uploading it to SVN everything is thrown in one place - is there some nice way to deal with it? Or I should deal with each project seperately?

EDIT:
probably I wrote it not clearm problem is when I check out project and I have to repair myself paths in plist file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to know and understand how your tools work. As far as I can assume the question arise because of insufficient understanding of your version-control tool and the question it's not really xcode-related.

Apache Subversion has a great manual: [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html); and I strongly advise you to check the chapters that describe the basics:

[**Chapter 1. Fundamental Concepts**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html)

[**Chapter 2. Basic Usage**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html)

Comment: point taken, but maybe I didn't make it clear - when I check out this project back to my computer it won't start, because of all that mess and I have to manually 'repair' paths in plist...

Comment: @FilipChwastowski why did you commit your project with broken paths in first place? You can fix the plist once or fix the directory structure and then commit the working project to the repository (you can choose to commit to other branch for logging / historical reasons and leave the branch with broken project as-is).

Comment: well, when everything was working (so were paths I think) and I uploaded project to my svn repo with success how could I know that i will check out a 'slightly different' project ;)